# SQL Group by, but allow duplicate if value is the same

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by, oracle-apex, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to group some max values by an ID (until here i got it figured out), and I also need to select the names from the persons with the max values, so my grouping should allow duplicates if two persons with that grouped ID have the same value (max).

Here's what I've got so far.

```
SELECT MGR,MAX(SAL) AS MaxSal
FROM EMP
WHERE MGR IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY MGR
```

Now I also need to extract the field `ENAME`, how could I do this, while grouping and also allowing duplicate groups when necessary ?

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: analytic functions is what you want, see https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rank-dense-rank-first-last-analytic-functions , one example is nearly a 100% hit

Comment: @Turo Indeed, seems like those functions are exactly what I was looking for. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is analytic functions. Here's how I achieved my desired result.

```
SELECT MGR,ENAME,SAL 
FROM
(
   SELECT MGR,ENAME,SAL,
   MAX(SAL) OVER (PARTITION BY MGR) AS MaxSal
   FROM EMP
)
WHERE SAL=MaxSal
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting Oracle 12c, one option uses window functions in the `order by` clause and a `fetch` clause:

```
select mgr, ename, sal
from emp
where mgr is not null
order by rank() over(partition by mgr order by sal desc)
fetch first row with ties
```